# summing an arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find a way to sum a group of numbers, however the numbers are not incremental, nor explicit.

I have a list that looks like this:

```
1 - 25
2 - 45
3 - 65
4 - 85
5 - 105
6 - 125
 etc.
```

As the position increments by one the value increments by 20.
which i can express as n = n*20+5

I need to know how to get the sum of any range from this list.

so say I need 4 to 6 (these will always be sequential)

> I need to add 85 + 105 + 125   for a total of 315

If I want 1-5 I need to add

> 25 + 45 + 65 + 85 + 105    for a total of 325

I want a way to mathematically express this when I am given a start point and end point and I need to sum all the values.

If there is a name for this that'd be great info too.

Comment: you may simply take the `middle` value and multiply it by the number of values. For example, if you want the sum of 1-5, do 65*5 which gives 325.

Comment: @rsadhvika this approach requires different formulas depending on whether you have an even or an odd number of terms - and when the number is even, the formula is no simpler than the one in my answer.

Comment: hey it works for even case too, your formula is identical to my approach.. for 1-6 we can do 75*6

Comment: rsadhvika - where did you get 75?

Comment: 75 is the `middle` of 65 and 85. Also 75 is the `middle` of "1-6" numbers

Comment: While this approach is interesting and simple form a "human" looking at a series, since - in my program - I know the first and last position, and how to figure that number - Lukas' formula works. rsadhvika's solution requires me to figure the midpoint and the series length. still interesting, and I'll play with both approaches. - Thanks rsadhvika

Comment: @jpmyob Lukas formula is identical to my approach. You may find it interesting to figure out why/how.. good luck :)

Comment: rsadhvika - I have already dug into it and I see why - thank you for add this to the discussion - yours is a simpler way of expressing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum equals $\frac{n}{2}\cdot (a_1 + a_n)$ where $a_1$ and $a_n$ are the first and last terms respectively.

This is called the arithmetic series formula.

Edit:  $\frac{3}{2}\cdot (85+125) = 315$ and  $\frac{5}{2}\cdot (25+105) = 325$

Comment: Lukas - thank you for responding - so I understand - can you put the figures I used in the two examples above - into this formula.

Comment: I added the calculations.

Comment: ok, this is facinatingly simple...I will have to read more - thank you.
so now Im curious... if I changed my increment value to 30 what would that look like... what is driving that increment?

Comment: The formula accounts for that: with a larger increment, the last term will be ”farther away“ from the first one, making for a larger sum. The formula is valid for any increment and any number of terms.

Comment: AWWW - Holy Cow - that's cool - thanks.